# Understanding how to estimate the model of Fung and Hsieh (2001) for the hedge funds risk factors

Tags: econometrics, finance, regression, applied-econometrics, asset-pricing

There is an old paper about the risk of hedge fund strategies that it gathers its focus in the trend followers. This is the [Fung and Hsieh (2001)](https://www.turtletrader.com/hsieh_fung_final_paper.pdf) paper.

$\textbf{Definition of Trend Followers (TFs):}$ Trend followers (namely hedge fund managers) attempt to profit from price movements. They capture ``market trends" commonly related to serial correlation in price changes. TFs trade only after they have observed certain price movements during a period.

The terms buying breakouts and selling breakdowns are often used to describe trend followers. These are very common characteristics of trend-following strategies. Breakout means that the price of an asset moves above a recent high, and buying breakouts refers to the strategy of going long when a breakout happens. Breakdown means that the price moves below a recent low, and selling breakdowns refers to the strategy of going short when a breakdown happens.

$\textbf{Definition of Trend:}$ A trend is a series of asset prices that move persistently
in one direction over a given time interval, where price changes exhibit positive serial correlation. Hence, a trend follower attempts to identify developing price patterns with this property and trade in the direction of the trend if and when this occurs.

The authors claim that hedge fund strategies typically generate option-like returns and that is why a linear factor model, that uses benchmark asset indices fails to explain them. By the use of [lookback straddles](https://fincyclopedia.net/derivatives/l/lookback-straddle) (exotic option that exist only in over the counter markets) to model trend-followers strategies, they can explain better the TFs' hedge funds returns than standard asset indices.

The set of risk factors, that explain trend following funds returns better according to the $R^2$ criterion, the five PTFS portfolios. Its factors are the Stock PTFS, Bond PTFS, Currency PTFS, three-month interest rate PTFS and Commodity PTFS. The term PTFS is an abbreviation of Primitive Trend-Following Strategy.

$\textbf{Definition of the PTFS:}$  The PTFS attempts to capture the largest price movement during the time interval. Consequently, the optimal payout of the PTFS is

$$S_{max}-S_{min}$$

where $S_{max}$ and $S_{min}$ stand for the the maximum and the minimum price achieved over a given time interval by the traded asset. The PTFS adds the possibility of trading on $S_{max}$ and $S_{min}$.

The delta of the lookback straddle is given by

$$\delta_{LB}=\left(1+\frac{\sigma^2}{2r}\right)\left(N(-b_3)-N(d_3)\right)+\frac{u}{\sigma}e^{-rT}\left(e^{\frac{2rb}{\sigma^2}}N(b_2)-e^{-\frac{2rb}{\sigma^2}}N(d_2)\right)$$

where

$$u=r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$$

$$d=ln\left(\frac{S}{Q}\right)$$

$$d_1=\frac{ln\left(\frac{S}{Q}\right)+uT}{s\sqrt{T}}$$

$$d_1=\frac{-ln\left(\frac{S}{Q}\right)+uT}{s\sqrt{T}}$$

$$d_1=\frac{-ln\left(\frac{S}{Q}\right)-uT}{s\sqrt{T}}$$

$$b=ln\left(\frac{M}{S}\right)$$

$$b_1=\frac{ln\left(\frac{M}{S}\right)-uT}{s\sqrt{T}}$$

$$b_2=\frac{-ln\left(\frac{M}{S}\right)-uT}{s\sqrt{T}}$$

$$b_3=\frac{ln\left(\frac{M}{S}\right)-(u+\sigma^2)T}{s\sqrt{T}}$$

Here $Q$ and $M$ stand for the minimum and maximum prices, respectively of the asset since the inception of the lookback straddle.

Reading the paper, I am missing the point how the authors use the above formulas to estimate their model.

It seems to me that their model is a five factor model where $X_i=\left\{\text{Stock PTFS, Bond PTFS, Currency PTFS, three-month interest rate PTFS, Commodity PTFS}  \right\}$, $i=1,\dots,5$ such that

$$R^{TS}_{HFs}=\alpha+<\beta_i,X_i>$$

or

$$R^{TS}_{HFs}=\alpha + \beta_1 S_{PTFS}+\beta{2}B_{PTFS} +\beta_3 Cr_{PTFS}+\beta_4 I_{PTFS}^{\text{three-month}}+\beta_5 CM_{PTFS}\tag{1}$$

Based on $(1)$, I believe that this is the model in a linear formulation, though I can not understand how the formulas of the lookback straddle can be used to estimate the above.

1. Do the authors mean that they use the lookback straddle formulas to calculate the returns somehow?
2. According to this link [there are different hedge fund strategies, but which of them belongs to the Trend following funds?](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/hedge-fund-strategies/)